# C++ code for concatanation of two Bstr strings

Tags: c++, string, com, concatenation, bstr

I am trying to concatenate two bstr_t one is char '#' and the other is an int (which I convert it to bstr_t) and gonna return it as a bstr (e.g '#'+'1234' as '#12345'). however, after concatenation the final result only contains '#'. I don't know where I am making mistake.

```
function(BSTR* opbstrValue)
{
    _bstr_t sepStr = SysAllocString(_T("#"));

    wchar_t temp_str[20]; // we assume that the maximal string length for displaying int can be 10
    itow_s(imgFrameIdentity.m_nFrameId, temp_str, 10);
    BSTR secondStr = SysAllocString(temp_str);
    _bstr_t secondCComStr; 
    secondCComStr.Attach(secondStr);

    _bstr_t wholeStr = sepStr + secondCComStr;

    *opbstrValue = wholeStr.Detach();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly simplify your function by taking advantage of [_bstr_t](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx)'s constructor. [One](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k3ebasf.aspx) of its overloads takes a `const _variant_t&` as an input parameter and parses it as a string. Hence, your function could look as follows:

```
void function(BSTR* opbstrValue)
{
    _bstr_t res(L"#");
    res += _bstr_t(12345); //replace with imgFrameIdentity.m_nFrameId

    *opbstrValue = res.Detach();
}
```